# Java software editor / syntax highlighter

Tags: java, editor, syntax-highlighting, text-editor

I have to build a software editor for Java, so think of just a very simplified Netbeans / Eclipse. The first area which I want to do is the Syntax Highlighting.

I found a few libraries / open source editors such as jEdit, BlueJ and jsyntaxpane which will be useful for building my own.

What I am looking for though is any literature / journals / books / articles which explain the process of writing a syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily for you, jEdit provide a [syntax package](http://syntax.jedit.org/), which is a Java Bean. There is also [Jintilla](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jintilla/). If you have to code this yourself, you want to parse the file and tokenize the items found. Apply different colours to the different tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Im not the Java guy but since you said:

> What I am looking for though is any literature / journals / books / articles which explain the process of writing a syntax highlighter.

Here are some **.NET** links from codeproject:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/SyntaxHighlighting.aspx
(Reusable Control) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/SyntaxRichTextBox.aspx
(Silverlight) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SL2TextBoxWsSynParser.aspx

Here are some **.NET** Intellisense links:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/JGIntelli.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/diy-intellisense.aspx

*I couldn't find any Java links for your question on codeproject*

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to write one yourself, look for a text book on parsers and compilers.  What you need is a lexer to break up the code in tokens and then highlight based on the token type.  It's duplicating code that's already available, but you'll learn a lot doing it.